# Vue-test-utils cannot call text on empty wrapper

Tags: vue.js, vue-test-utils

I have the following html template

```html
<div>
    <li class="posted-comment" v-for="commentDetail in commentDetail" :key="commentDetail.id"
    @mouseover="hoverIn()" @mouseout="hoverOut()">
        <div class="comment-user-avatar"><img :src="commentDetail.img_url"></div>
        <div class="comment-user-details">
            <span class="distinct-user-name">{{ commentDetail.name}}</span>
            <span class="distinct-user-title">{{ commentDetail.user }}</span>
            <span class="full-stop">.</span>
            <span class="distinct-time-stamp">{{ commentDetail.time}}</span>
        </div>
        <div class="comment-info-block-wrapper">
            <div id="distinct-user-comment">
                {{ commentDetail.text}}
            </div>
        </div>
    </li>
```

Calling wrapper.find('li.posted-comment .comment-info-block-wrapper #distinct-user-comment') says cannot call text on empty wrapper, looks like the "distinct-user-comment" id cant be found

```js
describe('Comment.vue', () => {
  it('renders distinct user comment class', () => {
    const string = 'So what the German automaker is likely to focus on today is the bigger picture. This will be the first time we see the Taycan free from any prototype bodywork.';
    const wrapper = shallowMount(Comment)
    expect(wrapper.find("li.posted-comment .comment-info-block-wrapper #distinct-user-comment").text()).equal(string)
  })
})
```

Comment: I cannot reproduce the problem with the code you've shown.

Comment: Maybe somewhere you just dropped the value of that component

Comment: This problem may be related to using `shallowMount()`. Have you tried `mount()` instead?